# Django - Could i18n.set_language() store in User profile

Tags: python, django, internationalization, django-users

I would like [`i18n.set_language()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/i18n/internationalization/#the-set-language-redirect-view) to store the language into an eventually available [user profile](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users) when a language is selected by a user.

Django should also use this to [discover](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/topics/i18n/#how-django-discovers-language-preference) my language.

Is it a good idea ? If yes how could I do it ?

Comment: [django-user-accounts](http://django-user-accounts.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) handles that.

Comment: Actually I already use _django-registration_ which does a part of what _django-user-accounts_ does, and I already have a user profile configured. That's why I would like to know how to it manually.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. **See [How to override a view from an external Django app -> How to override without forking -> Overriding a view](http://blog.yourlabs.org/post/19777151073/how-to-override-a-view-from-an-external-django-app)** to make "i18n.set_language() to store the language into an eventually available user profile"
2. **Copy [django-user-accounts middleware](https://github.com/pinax/django-user-accounts/blob/master/account/middleware.py#L7)** and change `get_language_for_user`.
3. **Place the middleware after `django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware`**, because this sets the default language based on the request so that's still useful for anonymous visitors, so you want this executed before your own middleware.

Comment: I did it but I'm not sure where to put it in `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` and do I have to remove `django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware` ? Also I don't know how I can override `i18n.set_language()` to get the language stored in the profile.

Comment: Sorry I missed that part about set_language, answer updated (with a note about placing the middleware in settings, after -again- reading Django's source code).

Comment: I will try the view override. Aparently the middleware have also to be placed after `django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware`